# Focus back on remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize2

Is there a straightforward way of focusing back to the input once a token is removed? I tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
$('#myDiv').on('tokenize:tokens:remove', function(event, value, text) {
  dostuff();
  $(this).trigger('tokenize:focus'); //refocus same input
});
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

Here is a quick demo https://jsfiddle.net/DarthShekhar/xpvt214o/775415/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, posting if anybody needs it in future.

`$(this).trigger('tokenize:select', [true]);`

[Issue here](https://github.com/dragonofmercy/Tokenize2/issues/56)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the jquery [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) on the element

```
$(this).focus();
```

Comment: This was my first guess but unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can create a demo

Comment: Updated with demo

Comment: The demo does not do anything

Comment: You can try typing any of the phrases africa, america, asia, europe or ocenia, you will see suggestion in drop down. Select any and then can remove with the 'X' opposite to the selected token.

Comment: maybe do a click event on the X and call focus after X is clicked.

Comment: That was something I really didn't want to do, its a hack, but I can live with it until I find a better solution.